# LyX: number table by section suddenly default, how to remove

Tags: floats, numbering, lyx

I just installed the newest version of LyX 2.0.4 and notice that the table numbering is by section. How do I remove this so that it is naturally incremented for each table created, like it was before?

Edit: Here is a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz1agkkmmcja5df/tables.lyx)

Comment: I've also found that labels have to be placed after captions and within the float environment, otherwise you can have a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for posting a nice minimum working example. Two things to note here:
1. You are using the report class.
2. By "section" you mean "chapter".

Either change your chapters to sections or go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and add the following:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

Note that this assumes you have the `chngcntr` package installed.

Comment: Thank you, it works :) But why change chapters to sections? I didn't see any difference in the names. `Chapter 3` is still `Chapter 3`

Comment: @Wilhelmsen I don't understand. If you change the chapters to sections, I don't think you should see "Chapter 3".

Comment: Well, I do. If I use only `\counterwithout...` I get missing package. Using `chngcntr` it works, but I still see Chapter. Although, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Using `chngcntr` will not change your chapters to sections. To change your chapters to sections, in LyX go to one of your chapter titles and press "tab" or click on the upper-left where it says "chapter" and scroll to "section". You would see the 1 become a 0.1 and "chapter" will be excluded.

Comment: I see, thank you. But why is it like this? Never had to add that to the preamble before

Comment: Perhaps because chapters are usually long and it makes it easier on readers to not have large table numbers.